# Find how many maximum column values a row has

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am working on an assignment in C++ and I have been stuck at the same point for days now, I know I am overlooking something, but I can't tell what it is.

The question is:

> *m* dogs compete in *n* categories and each gets a point between 0 and 10. How many categories did the absolute winner dog (the one with the most overall points) win?

I am supposed to work with the simple methods in computing such as: maximum search, linear search, logarithmic search, counting, array summing, *etc*. So I can't use `max(a, b)` or things like that.

My program is currently structured in the following way:

1. There is a summing function that takes as input a vector and tells me the sum
2. A `MaxSearch` function that takes as input the whole matrix and then uses the summation matrix to find the row with the maximum points (this would be the absolute winner dog's row index)

And then I have tried multiple different options to move on from here but none of them work, here are the functions I have used so far, 'mat' is the input matrix that I get either form a file or from console:

```
int ArraySum(const vector<int>& z)
{
    int s=0;
    for(unsigned i=0; i<z.size(); i++) s+=z[i];
    return s;
}


int MaxRow(const vector<vector <int> >& mat)throw(Range_Error)
{
    if(mat.size()==0) throw EmptyRange;
    int maxrow=ArraySum(mat[0]);
    int ind=0;
    for(unsigned i=1; i<mat.size();++i){
    int s=ArraySum(mat[i]);
    if(s>maxrow){
        maxrow=s;
        ind=i;}
    }
    return ind;
}

//And this is where I am stuck
```

Comment: use `std::for_each` instead of `ArraySum`, `std::find` instead of `MaxRow` and `std::count` to find the answer.

Comment: I am not allowed to use any of those, I can only use the few simple functions I have mentioned and to embed those functions. I think I need one more maxsearch to find max values in columns, and a counter function to compare the max value in a column to the maxrow and add 1 when they are the same, but I am lost in the details.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood the problem. Less words and more code:

```
int MaxValueRow(const vector<vector <int> >& mat, int col)
{
  int m = math.size();
  int ind = 0;
  int maxPoints = mat[0][col];

  for (int r = 1; r < m; r++) {
    if (mat[r][col] > maxPoints) {
      maxPoints = mat[r][col];
      ind = r;
    }
  }

  return ind; // The correct return value is ind
}

int CountWins(const vector<vector <int> >& mat)
{
  int winnerRow =  MaxRow(mat);
  int count = 0;

  int n = mat[0].size();
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (MaxValueRow(i) == winnerRow)
      count++;
  }

  return count;
}
```

Where `MaxValueRow(col)` returns the row with the maximum value at that column.

Comment: It is not working, I have tried maxValueRow separately with a few values, but it doesn't return the row with the maximum value at the column and I can't tell why not.

Comment: Well, I have not tested the code, I have written the code in the fly. Let me check.

Comment: I have tried that out but it still just returns 0 for any matrix I try.

Comment: Can you give me a copy of your full code?, I don't want to write all from scratch.